# How to access @ResponseBody of spring controller in dropzone angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dropzone.js

I'm new to Spring MVC and AngularJS and I am trying to implement a [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) upload feature in my web app.

In a usual `$http.post` method, I am able to retrieve the `@ResponseBody` of my spring controller in my angularjs controller as a promise.

I would like to achieve the same results for Dropzone upload. In my dropzone angularjs directive, I tried accessing the response of the "success" event handler, however, it returns an undefined (log from spring controller showed successful upload of data). Seems like executing the `dropzone.processQueue()` does not retrieve the response data from spring like a $http.post request. Are there anyway of retrieving the `@ResponseBody` of the spring controller for Dropzone uploads similar to that of a `$http.post`?

### dropzone directive

```
myApp.directive("dropzone", [function(){
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs){
        var config = {
            url: "http://localhost:9000/app/file-upload/upload",
            maxFilesize : 1,
            paramName: "uploadfile",
            parallelUploads: 1,
            autoProcessQueue: false
        };
        var eventHandlers = {
            'success': function (file, response) {
                scope.csvRawData = response.data;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
        };
        dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config);
        angular.forEach(eventHandlers, function(handler, event) {
            dropzone.on(event, handler);
        });
        scope.processDropzone = function() {
            dropzone.processQueue();
        };
    };
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        link: link
    }
}]);
```

### Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/app/file-upload/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String parseUploadCsv(MultipartHttpServletRequest request){

        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];

        try{
            Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
            while (itr.hasNext()){
                String uploadedFile = itr.next();
                MultipartFile csvFile = request.getFile(uploadedFile);
                bytes = csvFile.getBytes();
            }
            System.out.println(bytes);
            String csvRawData = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
            //System.out.println(csvRawData);
            return csvRawData;
        }catch (Exception e){
            //System.out.println(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest trying out the [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) or similar file upload library desinged for angular.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!